# Jquery search from the start of the letter

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using jQuery UI autocomplete and it is not searching items that start with the letter. Will someone help me please!

Here's my code:

```
var my= [
    "Urbana, IL",
    "Ursa, IL",
    "Utica, IL",
    "Valier, IL",
    "Valmeyer, IL",
    "Van-Orin, IL",
    "Vandalia, IL"
];

my.sort();

$("#location-input").autocomplete({ 
    maxResults: 15,
    delay:1,
    minLength:1,
    source: function(request, response) {
        var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(my, request.term);

        response(results.slice(0, this.options.maxResults));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code *will* match the typed letter if it exists anywhere in the word. If you want to match **only items that *begin* with** the typed letter, jQuery recommends using a dynamic regex, like below:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      var my = [
        "Urbana, IL",
        "Ursa, IL",
        "Utica, IL",
        "Valier, IL",
        "Valmeyer, IL",
        "Van-Orin, IL",
        "Vandalia, IL"
      ];
      my.sort();

      $("#location-input").autocomplete({
        maxResults: 15,
        delay: 1,
        minLength: 1,
        source: function(request, response) {
          var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
          response($.grep(my, function(item) {
              return matcher.test( item );
          }).slice(0, this.options.maxResults));
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  Type "v" (will find). Type "i" (won't find): <input type="text" id="location-input">
</body>
</html>
```

Above, the `.slice(0, this.options.maxResults)` is added to limit the results to `maxResults`. In the examplem 15.

Comment: Thanks it works!! But I have one issue. I have more items in my array than what I showed you, And when I search its very slow to the point it doesn't show the results that why I have the maxResults to be 15. How do I tell it to only send me the maxim Results

Comment: What is "send me the maxim"?

Comment: I mean this maxResults: 15,

Comment: Added `.slice(0, this.options.maxResults)`. Check updated answer.

Comment: No problem Thank you so much